# Need a Google Sheet solution to combine different time series with varying dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dynamicquery

I have Dataset of several time series. The dates on Column1 and Values on Column 2 of all the series but dates are varying. Need a Google Sheet solution to combine all the dates into one Column and Values of different series in different Columns

**Sample Data set.**

[Sample Data set image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFFQR.png)

**Expected Result**
[Expected Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApXeM.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first tab is called 'data' then this formula should produce the expected result:

`=QUERY({{data!A1:B1,"Value"};{data!A2:B,transpose(split((REPT(data!B1&"|",rows(data!A2:A))),"|"))};{data!C2:D,transpose(split((REPT(data!D1&"|",rows(data!C2:C))),"|"))};{data!E2:F,transpose(split((REPT(data!F1&"|",rows(data!E2:E))),"|"))};{data!G2:H,transpose(split((REPT(data!H1&"|",rows(data!G2:G))),"|"))}},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3")`

I created this example sheet to demonstrate:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16_Xm-BVhE3AXvcr6dQe_OpgSUGYIOwt2R8brr-JS3xE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris Hick. The solution works. But for a dataset with than 1000 rows it doesn't work.